# Is there a way to sort the newest questions by votes or status of has an accepted answer or not?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

SO is a great place for asking questions and getting answers as well as looking for questions that have already been answered.  Somewhat a "get in, get your stuff, and get out" kind of way.

What I have learnt is that SO is also a great place to improve our overall knowledge on a continuous basis:

- look at highly rated questions for a tag or set of tags
- look at frequently viewed questions for a tag or set of tags

While it is easy to look at the newest questions for a tag or set of tags, seems like there is no way of:

- filtering / sorting newest questions by votes / views / number of answers
- filtering / sorting newest questions by their status of "has an accepted answer or not"
- weeding out down-voted questions

Is this a missing feature or there are workarounds that I am missing?  I have subscribed to the "Newest questions" feed and I do use the associated link that tries to display the questions for the day but it has very limited navigational convenience.

Thoughts?

Comment: I know that you can do it by votes and likely if the question is "unanswered", but I don't think views factor so much into the default sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorts that appear to be available are

- newest: recency of the question being asked
- frequent: appears to be primarily related to "views" over answers or votes.
- votes: sorted by number of votes on the question itself
- active: appears to be mostly related to recency of any comments and answers.

Newest and votes are easy enough to understand, but I'm not sure what algorithm goes into calculating "frequent" and "active". The answers above are based on my guesses from observation.

There's a separate set of filters for viewing "unanswered" question:

- mytags: questions asked that match my set of preferred tags that have no accepted answers
- newest: most recent questions asked that have no accepted answers
- votes: sorted by votes applied to the question
- no answers: meaning I think no answered accepted, although several may have been offered